# Logback layout presentation header at bottom of file?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm programmatically configuring Logback and trying to set custom headers and footers to the log files when they rollover. To do this I've extended PatternLayout with a custom class:

```
class LogbackAdapterLayout extends PatternLayout {

  @Override
  public String getPresentationHeader() {
    return "head";
  }

  @Override
  public String getPresentationFooter() {
    return "foot";
  }
}
```

But I end up with this:

```
head
08:49:52.464 [main] TRACE com.example.test - Testing 0
08:49:52.467 [main] TRACE com.example.test - Testing 1
08:49:52.467 [main] TRACE com.example.test - Testing 2
08:49:52.467 [main] TRACE com.example.test - Testing 3
08:49:52.467 [main] TRACE com.example.test - Testing 4
08:49:52.467 [main] TRACE com.example.test - Testing 5
08:49:52.467 [main] TRACE com.example.test - Testing 6
08:49:52.467 [main] TRACE com.example.test - Testing 7
08:49:52.467 [main] TRACE com.example.test - Testing 8
08:49:52.467 [main] TRACE com.example.test - Testing 9
head
foot
```

I'm using logback 1.1.3, configuring programmatically, wrapping the LogbackAdapterLayout with a LayoutWrappingEncoder, which is added to a RollingFileAppender (with SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy and FixedWindowRollingPolicy)

Is there something I've configured incorrectly? Is there a way I can stop the header being at the bottom of the log file?

EDIT: A little more information, the header at the top is added when the new log file is created, the "header" at the bottom is added on rollover, I can change LogbackAdapterLayout and run again and the new header string will appear at the bottom of the rolled over log, with the old one unchanged at the top.

Comment: have you solved an issue?